# Problem when trying to make the image change when hovering over items in a list. Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, mouseevent, attr

When trying to select another item from the list the image does not change. I checked with console.log and it seems the selector doesn't change when I hover over the other items in my list, so Image A is always displayed.

```js
$(".list li a").mouseenter(function(){
  var currentImage = $(".honda").attr("data-cover");
  // console.log(currentImage)
  $(".honda").parent().prev().prev().find("img").attr("src", currentImage);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.img-test {
  background-color: rgb(0, 230, 12);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(76, 102, 117);
  border: 1px solid rgb(155, 161, 180);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list>li>a {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.list li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(194, 79, 188, 0.664);
  color: #ffcb6b;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-test"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/bfbfbf/000.jpg&text=Default+BG"></div>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">Image A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Image B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Image C</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="images">
  <div class="honda" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/de2c2c/fff.jpg&text=A"></div>
  <div class="honda" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/44679e/fff.jpg&text=B"></div>
  <div class="honda" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/ffe554/000.jpg&text=C"></div>
</div>
```

I am looking for the selector to change when the mouse passes over a list element and for the image to change. Tried various things but no significant changes.

I also add an image of the problem.

On the left is my current result. All 3 elements are stacked in the same place. On the right is shown how it should work.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: If you don't mind tweaking your markup, you can try something like this:

```js
var $displayImage = $('.img-test img');

$(".list li a").on('mouseenter', function() {
  var currentImage = $(this).attr("data-cover");
  $displayImage.attr("src", currentImage);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.img-test {
  background-color: rgb(0, 230, 12);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(76, 102, 117);
  border: 1px solid rgb(155, 161, 180);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list>li>a {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.list li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(194, 79, 188, 0.664);
  color: #ffcb6b;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img-test"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/bfbfbf/000.jpg&text=Default+BG"></div>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/de2c2c/fff.jpg&text=A">Image A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/44679e/fff.jpg&text=B">Image B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/ffe554/000.jpg&text=C">Image C</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Option 2**: If you want to maintain the current markup, you can try something like this:

```js
var $displayImage = $('.img-test img');

$(".list li a").on('mouseenter', function() {
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  var currentImage = $(".honda").eq(index).attr("data-cover");

  $displayImage.attr("src", currentImage);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.img-test {
  background-color: rgb(0, 230, 12);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.list li {
  list-style: none;
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(76, 102, 117);
  border: 1px solid rgb(155, 161, 180);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list>li>a {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.list li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(194, 79, 188, 0.664);
  color: #ffcb6b;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-test"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/bfbfbf/000.jpg&text=Default+BG"></div>
<ul class="list">
  <li><a href="#">Image A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Image B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Image C</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="images">
  <div class="honda" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/de2c2c/fff.jpg&text=A"></div>
  <div class="honda" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/44679e/fff.jpg&text=B"></div>
  <div class="honda" data-cover="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/ffe554/000.jpg&text=C"></div>
</div>
```

**Optional**: You can [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) the images for better performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response and recommendation. I had a similar code and I wanted to give the images a transition but the styles are applied to the <li> elements as well. I wanted to have the images and the <li> separate so that the tränsiton styles would not affect the text.
Would preload also help with local files or is it only for external files?

Comment: @3Code does this answer answers your original question?

Comment: Well what I need is to keep the <li> elements and images separate (if possible) and be able to link them with jquery. <li>Image A</li> displays Image A, etc.

Comment: @3Code I've added "Option 2". I think that is what you're looking for. Kindly check it out